# Android sqlite does not support joint multi-table query

Tags: android, sqlite

The data checked by `String sql = "select * from disease order by id"` can display in listview.

But `String sql = "SELECT disease.id id, disease.DiseaseName_CN DiseaseName_CN,chufang.xuewei_cn xuewei_cn" + " FROM disease,chufang where chufang.diseaseid=disease.id order by id";`can not check the data. It can execute in firefox and ADB. But it can not display the data which is checked by the back line in the emulator.

Why this is happened?

Comment: And what happens when you try it?

Answer (score -1):

some of the standard features of SQL which are not supported by SQLite are : Right outer join,
full outer join, foreign key constraint, nested transactions and some forms of ALTER statement

Comment: None of these are used in the question.